# Record audio on webpage - iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, audio, web, record

One of my clients asked me to develop a webpage which allows the users to record his own voice through his microphone. I did it using jRecorder (which uses a Flash file), which works quite fine.

However, the client now wants the webpage to be functional on iOS and Android tablets and phones.

So my question is: Is it now possible to access the device's microphone from a webpage (thus, from the mobile browser) on iOS and Android? If yes, what technology/API should I be using?

I heard about Web Audio API, getUserMedia and HTML5 Audio Capture. It seems like those are not totally supported by mobile browsers. Most of the articles I found about those are quite old however and things could have changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for although it is a bit of a hack:

http://rioleo.github.io/safari-audiorecord-io6/

I think we should all petition Apple to open up audio recording in Safari, since they already allow video+audio recording.